# How to use Reidemeister moves to show the two representations are the same?

Tags: geometry, knot-theory, low-dimensional-topology

I'm trying to show the two links in the picture attached are the same, But I'm having trouble figuring out what my first move should be. [image]

Comment: Try making the first one out of two pieces of string and see if you can lay it out as in the second diagram.  This might give you some intuition for how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sequence of Reidemeister moves which brings the first diagram of the Whitehead link to the second.

[image: Sequence of Reidemeister moves between two projections of the Whitehead link]

Comment: Is there a way to gain intuition for these problems? Does working them out with actual string help?

Comment: Also, for III Reidemeister moves, doesn't the strand have to be completely under or completely over the crossing?

Comment: I have found string useful. I found this sequence be manipulating mental string and reducing it to moves. Reidemeister III can be thought of as all stands moving simultaneously, or any one moving by itself.